# mms protocol on java

Tags: download, protocols, mms, java

Hi
I want to write an application to download a MMS video stream
Is there any J2SE class to make me able work with MMS protocol?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MMS is implemented over SOAP. Just use any SOAP parser available in java to read the messages. However before you can read messages you need to have then sent to you. To do that you need to sign up with an aggregator (Mobile Messenger, Ericsson, etc.). Once you signup w/ an aggregator they will send you an API doc w/ specific instructions, however, basically MMS is just a multipart HTTP request w/ a SOAP part.